# why DropDown() helper method does not display the dropdown when it was used in a C# block?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

i have the following view code to generate a drop down list control.when the code was written in the C# block it would not display the drop down

here is my code

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Html.DropDownList("id", Model.catColl);    
}
```

but when i write it outside of the C# block it displays.. why this happens and how do i fix this?

Comment: Because your evaluating it inside a code block (but not outputting the result) - you could do `@{ var dropdown = tml.DropDownList("id", Model.catColl); }` and then `@dropdown to display the result, bit what would be the point. What are you trying to acheive?

Comment: @zeelong It is possible that you have the block inside another block. can you post more code of your view?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i want to load that data to DDL and display it. but i want to do it in the C# code block

Comment: Then do it as per the code in my first comment (assign it to a variable inside the code block, and outside the code block use `@dropdown`). But again, what an earth would be the point of doing that?

Comment: @StephenMuecke some people who uses teleriks have seen using it like that

Comment: @zeelong, If you want it inside a code block, you can just use it like you use it elsewhere - `@Html.DropDownList("id", Model.catColl);` - i.e. with the leading `@` symbol. But your example makes no sense since its not even inside a form.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever inside the `@{ }` should be a **C# Code**, Whatever outside of it, should be **ASP.NET Code**.

If you want to combine the two in order to display C# values inside HTML, then you can use the following style: @SomeProperty

Example:

```
<h1>@ViewBag.Title</h1>
```

Fix for your problem, will be to put the `DropDownList` outside:

```
@Html.DropDownList("id", Model.catColl);
```

Comment: are you saying there is noway i could generate a dropdown list if i put the above code in C# code block???

Answer (score 1):

You should put `@` before `Html.DropDownList`. It will solve your problem.

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    @Html.DropDownList("id", Model.catColl);    
}
```